# QEMU: custom bootloader image not recognised

Tags: nasm, qemu, bootloader

I'm trying to run a sample bootloader from [a blog post](https://github.com/0xAX/linux-insides/blob/master/linux-bootstrap-1.md):

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7c00]

jmp boot

boot:
  mov ah, 0x0e
  mov bh, 0x00
  mov bl, 0x07
  mov al, '!'

  int 0x10
  jmp $

times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0xaa
db 0x55
```

`nasm -f bin boot.nasm` produces a 512 byte `boot` file with the following contents:

```
0000000: eb00 b40e b700 b307 b021 cd10 ebfe 0000
0000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000060: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000090: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00000a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00000b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00000c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00000d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00000e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00000f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000100: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000110: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000120: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000130: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000140: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000150: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00001a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00001b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00001c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00001d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00001e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00001f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 aa55
```

I would now expect `qemu-system-x86_64 boot` to use the `boot` file as raw disk image, recognise the last two bytes as boot sector marker and execute the instructions. Instead it fails to recognise the bootloader:

```
Booting from Hard Disk...
Boot failed: not a bootable disk
```

What am I doing wrong?

Software versions:

```
$ nasm -v
NASM version 2.11 compiled on Apr 26 2014
$ qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 2.1.0 (Debian 2.1+dfsg-4ubuntu6.3), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

Comment: [BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7c00]
what do these line mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the order of the boot flag values:

```
db 0x55
db 0xaa
```

Comment: Thanks! I see the blog post has been amended meanwhile.